# What’s the official in-universe classification of Thor and other Asgardians in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, asgardians

What’s the official in-universe classification of Asgardians in the MCU?

By official, I mean what category does S.H.I.E.L.D. put them into, i.e. “Alien,” “Human” or do they just designate them as “Gods?”

Comment: Why should what one agency on the the primitive planet Earth thinks Asgradians are be "official"? Shouldn't the classifications used by more advanced and knowledgeable and wdespead societies like the Skrull and the Kree be more official? Is there anything ever done by any Earlthling that had enough interstellar recognition to be considered official?

Comment: @M.A.Golding The Blip.

Comment: @M.A.Golding, I meant to ask in context of Earth as we consider Thor and the Asgardians Gods in the norse mythology but maybe S.H.I.E.L.D think otherwise

Comment: Is there one official SHIELD now? By "now", I mean post Endgame. I thought SHIELD was shattered into different factions in Winter Soldier. I haven't watched Agents of SHIELD.

Comment: @Taladris *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* definitely continues past *Winter Soldier*, but by the end of the series it has branched off into its own timeline (or multiple timelines?), so it's hard to say how canonical it is.  Other than Coulson and a brief appearance of Nick Fury, the only other crossover character is Lady Syf in a couple episodes.  We do see S.W.O.R.D. appear in *WandaVision*, so there's some relationship there...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Marvel released an 'Avengers Initiative' app to coincide with the release of The Avengers. There were dossiers and files on all of the main characters including Thor, who is referred to as an

> *"**extra-terrestrial being**"*

[image]

Comment: I wonder how a viking would have reacted after seeing this, because being told that their god is nothing but actually an alien, I think is quite heartbreaking

Comment: @shanu surely for a Viking the ability control lightning and to travel between worlds  would make even a real being nothing short of godlike. I'd imagine they'd be delighted to be able to meet Thor in person.

Comment: @shanu, I'm not sure that would be a meaningful distinction. Pantheistic gods tend to *not* be omni{scient,potent,present}; they're just really powerful beings. Said viking might well argue that what you insist on calling an "extraterrestrial" *is* a "god", and you aren't telling them anything they didn't already know.

Answer (score 20):

S.H.I.E.L.D. likely classifies Asgardians as aliens, judging by this dialogue from an early episode of *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*.

> SKYE: **So, Asgardians are aliens from another planet that visited us thousands of years ago?**
>
> AGENT COULSON: Or more.
>
> SKYE: **And because we couldn't understand aliens, we thought they were gods?**
>
> AGENT COULSON: **That's where our Norse mythology comes from.**
>
> SKYE: [sighs] That's too crazy. Do you think other deities are aliens, too? Vishnu for sure, right?
>
> <sub>*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* - S01E08 - "[The Well](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/The_Well)"</sub>

Odin probably would've agreed with this classification, since he clearly stated that MCU Asgardians aren't gods.

> LOKI: I went down to Midgard to rule the people of Earth as a benevolent god. Just like you.
>
> ODIN: **We are not gods. We are born, we live, we die. Just as humans do.**
>
> LOKI: Give or take 5000 years.
>
> <sub>*[Thor: The Dark World](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Thor:_The_Dark_World)* (2013)</sub>

Comment: I'd like to add that the Kree were considered as "gods" and "angels" when they arrived long before S.H.I.E.L.D., and they are, of course, aliens.

Comment: Odin's comment on not being gods is probably partly why Love&Thunder feels so off - as the Asgardians are in the same social clubs as things that do seem more supernatural.

Comment: @lucasbachmann: Generally agreed. They've definitely whipsawed back and forth on this point depending on the different showrunners.

Comment: Good answer but since Valorum gave a marvel approved dossier, I accepted their answer

Comment: I am intrigued by the Vishnu line tho

Comment: @shanu I believe that it’s a reference to how many avatars/incarnations Vishnu has had (many sources quote at least ten, and at least one source quotes forty two), and how expansive the stories of some of them are (the Ramayana, for example, makes even the most in-depth descriptions of Zeus's various incarnations seem absurdly terse by comparison). IOW, the assumption seems to be that the numerous well attested appearances of Vishnu in various forms on Earth imply that _something_ was real there (which is entirely possible in the MCU).

Comment: true, but wanted to clarify most people agree on the ten avatars instead of forty two  and  the tenth avatar is yet to make an appearance